# 3D vector Quotient of derivatives Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, derivative

I'm working in Matlab, However I want to apply quotient rule of derivatives of 3-D vector, as 
the 2-D quotient rule of derivatives is as:

```
V'' * U' - U'' * V'
```

or more specifically:

```
 for ii = 1:250
H(ii) = det([W2(ii) W1(ii); V2(ii) V1(ii); U2(ii) U1(ii);]);
end
```

how can I find 3-D quotient rule of derivatives? i.e where `W''` and `W'` represents 3rd Vector derivatives.
It can also be found by `det` but it accepts only square matrices.

Any Suggestions of finding 3-D Quotient or merging an axis information into other with the help statistics toolbox?

Comment: I think this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah, but I want to find some way from here as I dont think that it is possible.